# Parse json data seperated by new line in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I have been working on some project i have to work on JSON data separated by a newline. Here is the shape of the data:

```
{"response": "True", "controllerId": "2751", "level": "INFO", "logType": "watchdogResponse", "deviceId": "2751", "container": "firmware", "epoch": "1549996256", "module": "hostServices", "ts": "2019-02-13 00:00:56"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "jr", "logType": "running", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "rid": "EXTERNAL CALL", "val": "1549996260000"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "applicationMain", "logType": "wifi", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "networkStrength": "100.0"}
```

Now how can I parse it and I have to sort the data by its key.

Comment: By what key the data should be sorted?

Comment: Not by one key, like all the key are not in sorted order
ex: {a="1",b="2",c="3"}
      {b:"2", a="1",c="3"}

what I want is that file became like:
{a="1",b="2",c="3"}  a="1",b="2",c="3"}

Comment: I've updated my answer for sorted key order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the data is not a valid JSON string, but rather JSON strings separated by line breaks. So this is how the `data` can be converted into the array of objects with sorted key order:

```js
'use strict';

const data =
`{"response": "True", "controllerId": "2751", "level": "INFO", "logType": "watchdogResponse", "deviceId": "2751", "container": "firmware", "epoch": "1549996256", "module": "hostServices", "ts": "2019-02-13 00:00:56"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "jr", "logType": "running", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "rid": "EXTERNAL CALL", "val": "1549996260000"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "applicationMain", "logType": "wifi", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "networkStrength": "100.0"}`;

const sortedArrayOfObjects = data
  .split('\n')
  .map(JSON.parse)
  .map(obj => Object.entries(obj).sort().reduce(
    (o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v, o), {})
  );

console.log(sortedArrayOfObjects);
```

Comment: I want to work on all the key values,  not only the  'ts' one.
Can you help me to convert the invalid JSON file to proper JSON file

Comment: You can try this: `const validJSON = '[' + data.replace(/\n+(?=\{)/g, ',\n') + ']';`. Then you can parse: `const arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(validJSON);`

Comment: const validJSON =  data.replace(/\n+(?=\{)/g, ',\n');
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort using the date.

```js
let input = `{"response": "True", "controllerId": "2751", "level": "INFO", "logType": "watchdogResponse", "deviceId": "2751", "container": "firmware", "epoch": "1549996256", "module": "hostServices", "ts": "2019-02-13 00:00:56"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "jr", "logType": "running", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "rid": "EXTERNAL CALL", "val": "1549996260000"}
{"ts": "2019-02-13 00:01:10", "epoch": "1549996270", "level": "INFO", "module": "applicationMain", "logType": "wifi", "controllerId": "2751", "deviceId": "2751", "networkStrength": "100.0"}`

let out = input.split('\n').map(JSON.parse).sort((a, b) => {
  new Date(a.ts) > new Date(b.ts);
})
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, such sort function always returns `undefined`. And even with explicit `return` it would return `true` or `false` instead of required `-1`, `1`, or `0`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse JSON into a javascript object. To sort the data by their key in lexicographical order you could create an array using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then sort it using the [array's `sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
let obj = JSON.parse(data)
let arr = Object.entries(obj).sort()
```

Where `arr` would then be an array containing the key-value pairs (as arrays) sorted by their key.